# How to ADD in java through a runner class and a methods class?

Tags: java

ADDn - The first n (0 ≤ n ≤ 4) bits replicate and are concatenated to the first n bits. The last n bits are deleted

e.g. ADD3 ABCDEFGH becomes ABCABCDE

METHODS -

```
public class Methods 
{

public String ADD(String x, int y)
    {
        if(y > 0)
        {
        String output = x.substring(0,y);
        String output2 = x.substring(y, x.length() - y);
        return output + output + output2;
        }else {
            return x;
        }
}
```

RUNNER -

```
        import java.io.*;
        import java.util.*;
        public class Runner 
{

        public static void main(String []args)throws FileNotFoundException
        {
            Scanner in = new Scanner(new File("data.txt"));
            Methods md = new Methods();
            String cell = in.nextLine();
            String methods = in.nextLine();
            for (int x = 0; x < 5; x++)
            {
           if(methods.equals(("ADD2"))
                {
                    int i = Integer.parseInt(methods);
                    System.out.println( );
                }
```

DATAFILE- 
    ADD2 ABBCDFGG

I need it to print ABABBCDF

Comment: You may want to read up on what the modulus operator is and how it works (and why it's not appropriate for this problem): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation

Comment: @deyur You can use it for this problem, but you need to divide by 10, not 3.

Comment: Modulus won't work here either, at least not easily, @PaulBoddington, since 300 % 10 == 0; yet it definitely contains a 3, while 3 % 10 == 3.

Comment: @AlexanderHuszagh You can do it, but it's a bit of a mess. `if (n % 10 == 3 || n / 10 % 10 == 3 || n / 100 % 10 == 3)`.

Comment: True but for stuff like this, string comparisons are a lot easier.

Answer (score 1):

```
class Problem {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int num = 1000; num <= 2000; num++) {
            if (String.valueof(num).contains("3")) {
                System.out.println(num);
            }
        }
    }    
}
```